# How to number a given equation in the align* environment such that the number depends on the whole document?

Tags: align, amsmath

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
We have
\begin{align*}
x^{2} &= x\cdot x\\
&= x^{6/3} 
\end{align*}
for all real $x$
\end{document}
```

To illustrate, suppose I would like to number only the first equality. I tried the command `\tag{a}` where $a$ is a natural number, but the number thus generated seems to be fixed, *i.e.* I would still get the label (a) even if there is another labeled equation preceding equation (a). What I want is that (a) should be (a+1) when there is another equation labeled before equation (a), say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to tag equations in an `align*` environment, the `\tag` command does indeed uses a fixed equation 'number' etc. then.

The `align*` environment however does not count the equation number, but the `align` environment does. If specific equations should not be numbered, `\notag` suppresses the numbering then.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
We have
\begin{align}
x^{2} &= x\cdot x \\
&= x^{6/3} \notag
\end{align}

And once again:

\begin{align}
x^{2} &= x\cdot x  \\
&= x^{6/3} \notag
\end{align}

for all real $x$
\end{document}
```

However ... if `align*` is used, a non-fixed tagging can be used with a `faking` command, say `\tagitanyway`.

This command has an optional argument, which defaults to `equation` and must be a counter name. This counter is `\refstepcounter`ed then and a 'fixed' tag is applied, using `\the'countername'`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\tagitanyway}[1][equation]{\refstepcounter{#1}\tag{\csname the#1\endcsname}}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2 
\end{equation}
We have


\begin{align*}
x^{2} &= x\cdot x \tagitanyway \\
&= x^{6/3}
\end{align*}

And once again:

\begin{align*}
x^{2} &= x\cdot x \tagitanyway \\
& = x^{6/3} \\
& = x^{42/21} \tagitanyway 
\end{align*}

for all real $x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did not make my question clear enough. Sorry that I have to say that I literally know the align trick with \nonumber or \notag. But, since at most of time I need occasionally to number equations, I think align* solution would be better; for otherwise I have to extensively type "\nonumber" or "\notag". I hope now I have made it clear. :)

Comment: @Chou: Yes, this clearification would helped me ;-)

Comment: Thank you. It is somewhat disappointed to know that there is no such "service" out there for align*, frankly.

Comment: @Chou: I believe there is but I don't know/remember -- see my updated 'example' -- perhaps, I've reinvented the wheel ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, nice! Would be nice to have an example using another counter, since your code allows it.

Comment: @Sigur: Well, I thought of `subequation`, for example?